# Making the keys of an object passed as argument as local function variables

Tags: jquery, function, scope, arguments

I have a function which you can pass an object to. I then need all the vars within this object to become local variables. For instance

```
function ping(){
    alert(riff); //'raff'
}

ping({
    riff: 'raff'
});
```

The only way I can think to do it is looping the object and setting them one by one but that seems clunky. Any alternatives?

**Edit**: the return was to show what that variable would be like. The main thing I don't want is to have to go through another object to get to the data. I want the structure to be

```
 function.riff = 'raff'
```

rather than

```
 function.settings.riff = 'raff'
```

Comment: That's the principle, and it is considered a good practice. So, use it, it's not clunky (in JS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function ping(){
    for(var key in arguments[0]){
        this[key] = arguments[0][key];
    }
}
```

This currently the best answer I can come up with... any advances on this?

**Note** how the vars are added directly into the function rather than through an object in the function.

This is because I want to be able to overwrite private function vars with this object before they are used.

Answer (score 1):

use `$.extend` : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

```
function ping(options){
    var defaults = { riff : "foo raff" };
    /* merge defaults and options  */
    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    console.log(settings.riff); // "raff"
}

ping({
    riff: "raff"
});
```

JsBin example: http://jsbin.com/utinuc/1/edit

Comment: I don't want to store the varaibles within another object. I'm changing a ready built function and all of them branch from the function directly.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do

```
function ping(obj){
    return obj.riff;
}
```

or

```
function ping(obj){
    var riff = obj.riff;

    return riff;
}
```

Comment: Ah...all variables, well then Fabrizios answer is better :)